# How do I buy a MacBook Pro with a Russian keyboard in United States

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, internationalization, apple-store

I am looking for a MacBook Pro MJLQ2RU, but there is no such model on store.apple.com. It's the same as MJLQ2LL but with a Russian/English backlit keyboard. I chatted with support, but they don't know such model.

Are there any stores that sell Russian MacBooks in United States?

Comment: Would be much simpler to order special keyboard cover. You'll get Russian letters and protection for your keyboard :) Here is one of hundreds possible options: https://www.amazon.com/Kuzy-Language-Keyboard-Silicone-Cyrillic/dp/B00AVBHMPY

Comment: Will they be still glowing as original?

Comment: Most of them are transparent so I think it will.

Comment: Denis- I think you meant translucent.

Comment: Did you try asking in an Apple Store? They might be able to get one on special order.

Comment: @Tetsujin  It doesn't seem off topic to me.  Questions about how to get keyboards like Russian, Hebrew, etc.  not found in the US online store are common.  The answer is always the same -- you need to start calling stores yourself.  Apple support is useless, they just know zero about such language issues.

Comment: It's right there in "Basic Customer Support" for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin I will be very thankful if you provide a link that proves your words, because Apple Support told me that they can't help me with that and I need to go to Russia to get a Russian MacBook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can find out if some retail store might be able to get one of these for you is to contact them directly yourself.  I would try a store in a big city with a significant Russian community.  I have not heard of anyone finding it in the US, but you never know until you ask.

The online Apple store in the UK has them, if you are planning a trip there.